# How to impose initial condition for a duration of time?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

A reaction diffusion system contains 2 pde, $xc, xp$, and one ode, xnn. A variable in my coupled pde system, $xc(t,x,y)$, has a piecewice initial condition for a duration. I am trying to redo the simulations in an old article.

"$xc(t,x)$ in a rectangular region between (-20,+20) is raised to x0h for 6 seconds"

I don't have a problem with it's "piecewiseness" ("$xc(t,x,y)$ in a rectangular region between (-20,+20) is raised to x0h", which I express as `xc[0,x]==If[-mix < y < +mix && -mix< x <+mix, xc0h, xc0]`).

But I don't know how can I write an initial condition saying "$xc(t,x,y)$ in a square region between (-mix,+mix) is raised to xc0h **for 6 seconds**".

I tried to add it as an additional initial condition but it didn't worked. Do you have any idea?
For a fuller expression, this is the whole code:

```
mx = 600;
mix = mx/10;
mt = 600; 
xc0h  = 0.9;
 xc0 = 0.130;
 xp0  = 0.095;
xnn0  = 1;

 s = NDSolve[
  {
   D[ xc[t, x, y], t] == 
    20 (D [xc[t, x, y], t] + D[ xc[t, x, y], t]) + 
     8.1 (0.567 + (0.433 xp[t, x, y] )/(xp[t, x, y] + 4.0)) xnn[t, x, 
       y] (0.111 + (0.899 xc[t, x, y])/(0.7 + xc[t, x, y])) - (
     2.0 xc[t, x, y])/(0.1 + xc[t, x, y]) + 0.02,
   D[ xp[t, x, y], t] == 
    300 (D[ xp[t, x, y], x] + D[ xp[t, x, y], y]) - 0.17 xp[t, x, y],
   D[ xnn[t, x, y], 
     t] == (1 - xc[t, x, y]^2/(xc[t, x, y]^2 + 0.7^2)) - 
     xnn[t, x, y],
   xc[0, x, y] == If[-mix < y < +mix&&-mix < x < +mix, xc0h, xc0],
   xc[t, 0, y] == xc0,
   xc[t, mx, y] == xc0,
   xc[t, x, 0] == xc0,
   xc[t, x, mx] == xc0,
   xp[0, x, y] == xp0,
   xp[t, 0, y] == xp0,
   xp[t, mx, y] == xp0,
   xp[t, x, 0] == xp0,
   xp[t, x, mx] == xp0,
   xnn[0, x, y] == xnn0
   },
  {xc, xp},
  {t, 0, mt},
  {x, 0, mx},
  {y, 0, mx}]
```

Comment: Gram per second looks like speed, i.e. first derivative of the function, not its value.

Comment: @yarchik you mean ```D[X1[0,x],t]==If[-20<x<20,10,5]``` ? Then how can I indicate the duration? There should be a difference between keeping $(-20,20)$ region in this value for 6 seconds and 60 seconds right?

Comment: Hmm, I do not know, I am confused my the rectangular region, which is definitely a 2D region, not 1D.

Comment: Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Could you give a fuller description of the model?  What's `X1` and are there other variables?  What's the PDE?

Comment: @ChrisK I've added the whole code.

Comment: Your code runs, but it seems to hit a singularity around t=116: `{s1, s2} = {xp, xc} /. s[[1]];
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{s1[t, x, y], s2[t, x, y]}, {x, 0, mx}, {y, 0, mx}]
 , {t, 0, 116.2}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber sorry xnn0 supposed to be 1. My bad.

Comment: Could you add a verbal description, because a few things are still not clear: 1) there is no `X1` in your code, 2) the same time derivative shows up in three places in the first two equations, is this a typo? and 3) what are the other variables supposed to be doing when the one is fixed?

Comment: @ChrisK 1) , 2) yes you are right, I fixed those. While xp tends to go to zero the other variables oscillate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only $x$-dependence is in the initial conditions, and there is no $y$-dependence at all, we can remove all references to $x$ and $y$.  The resulting equations will be valid at all $(x,y)$.

We treat the initial conditions as parameters and obtain a solution with this code:

```
mt = 20;
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{
    D[xc[t], t] == 20 (D[xc[t], t] + D[xc[t], t]) + 
        8.1 (0.567 + (0.433 xp[t])/(xp[t] + 4.0)) *
        xnn[t] (0.111 + (0.899 xc[t])/(0.7 + xc[t])) - 
        (2.0 xc[t])/(0.1 + xc[t]) + 0.02,
   D[xp[t], t] == 300 (D[xp[t], t] + D[xp[t], t]) - 0.17 xp[t],
   D[xnn[t], t] == (1 - xc[t]^2/(xc[t]^2 + 0.7^2)) - xnn[t],   
   xc[0] == xc0,
   xp[0] == xp0,
   xnn[0] == xnn0},
  {xc, xp}, {t, 0, mt}, {xc0, xp0, xnn0}];
```

We can integrate out to a greater time, but after plotting the resulting (exponential) solutions we choose to plot only the shorter interval.  Plots can be produced with the following code.  The first plot is valid for positions $(x,y)$ where $x \notin (0,30)$ and the second plot is valid for positions $(x,y)$ where $0 < x < 30$. The third plot is valid for all $(x,y)$.

```
With[{
  xc0h = 0.9,
  xc0 = 0.130,
  xp0 = 0.095,
  xnn0 = 1},
 GraphicsColumn@{
   Plot[xc[xc0, xp0, xnn0][t] /. soln,
    {t, 0, mt}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"t", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(c\)]\)", 
      "Initial condition is \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(c0\)]\)"}],
   
   Plot[xc[xc0h, xp0, xnn0][t] /. soln,
    {t, 0, mt}, GridLines -> Automatic,
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"t", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(c\)]\)", 
      "Initial condition is \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(c0h\)]\)"}],
   
   Plot[xp[xc0h, xp0, xnn0][t] /. soln,
    {t, 0, mt}, GridLines -> Automatic,
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"t", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(p\)]\)", 
      "Initial condition is \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(c0h\)]\)"}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that the DE for $x_p$ is not coupled to $x_c$ or to $x_{nn}$, so its solution is independent of the initial conditions $x_c(0)$ and $x_{nn}(0)$.  It may be a little misleading to label the third plot with the same title as others.  It is also misleading to not put the other ICs in the plot titles as well.